# How to do realtime fetching in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, fetch, real-time

Hi in my project there is comment section for a video.So what I'm expecting is showing the comments immediately after a user post it.I've tried `componentWillUpdate()` method.But it is  re-rendering the UI everytime,so causes some shaking in UI.Also I've tried to call the `fetch` method within the promise of `postComment`.That means within the fetch of posting a comment I'm trying to call the next fetch for showing the submitted comments.But no use.Following is the code I've tried

**code**

```
postComment(){
fetch(GLOBAL.COMMENT + `${this.props.id}/new/0`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': token,
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            comment_content: this.state.text

        })
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseData) => {

        this.setState({
            text: '',
            isLoad: false
        })
    }).then(() => {
        fetch(GLOBAL.GET_COMMENT + `${this.state.unit_id}/`, {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': token
                }
            }).then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseData) => {
                this.setState({
                    comment: responseData.data,
                    tab2: true,
                    tab3: false,
                    isLoading: false

                })
            });
    })

}
```

Is there any solution for this? Please help.Any help is appreciated.Thank you!

Comment: What you need to do is change the state after a comment is added so it rerenders automatically and displays all comments as soon as they are added. So if the comments are on the back end, after the request is finished, call the function that brings all comments and update state.

Comment: You can add the new posted comment to your flatlist `data` without fetch. You  don't need to fetch again

Comment: @squeekyDave So what change do I need to make in my existing code?Please help.

Comment: @anu So I assume you have your comments on the back end stored in a DB? If that is the case, then after the post comment request has finished, call a function that will fetch all comments and set the state with the newly fetched comments, which will do a re-render and you will see the new comments as soon as they are posted.

Comment: @squeekyDave So instead of this fetch within promise I've to do something like this `((then) => getComments() )` I'm I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it will look something like this, I am not sure how the rest of your code is set up so take this with a pinch of salt.

```
getComments() {

  fetch(GLOBAL.GET_COMMENT + `${this.state.unit_id}/`, {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': token
                }
            })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseData) => {
                this.setState({
                    comment: responseData.data,
                    tab2: true,
                    tab3: false,
                    isLoading: false

                })
            });
    })

};

postComment() {
  fetch(GLOBAL.COMMENT + `${this.props.id}/new/0`, {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
              'Authorization': token,
              'Accept': 'application/json',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
              comment_content: this.state.text

          })
      })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseData) => {

          this.getComments();
      })

}
```